# Set State of Functional Component While Unit Testing in Jasmine

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Bar() {
 const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState([]);

 const disableSubmit = React.useMemo(() => {
  return myState.length === 0
 }, [myState]);

 // logic to get myState data by making API call
 setMyState(getMyStateData());

 const onSubmit = () => {
  // do some validation and make API call
 };
 
 return (
  <form
   className="form-wrapper"      
   onSubmit={event => props.onSubmit(event)}
  >
   // logic to display myState data
   <button className="btn custom-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={disableSubmit}>
     Submit
   </button>
  </form>
 );
}
```

I am using Jasmine to do unit testing on my components.

I want to write a unit test to simulate the click event on submit button but I can't do this until the value of `myState` is not set to some array with `length>0`.

How can I set the value of `myState` in my unit test?

I have already tried using `instance` and then setting the value of `myState` but it throws an error that `component.instance()` is `undefined`.

I also came across `setState` but I found out that it only works for class components.

So, how can I set the value of `myState` in my unit test?

Comment: You set it by interacting with the component, as a user would. From what you've shown it's not clear specifically what that would look like, the setter isn't invoked anywhere.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the setter which gets data based on the response from an axios client which makes the API call.

Comment: That's almost certainly wrong anyway because if an API call is being made it's asynchronous and if you get a result back it's as a promise, but if the state comes from outside the component you could use a _test double_ of the collaborator (which here just magically appears in scope, still not a [mre]) or look into e.g. MSW.